# How can use stream API for divide the array into sub array

Tags: java, arrays, list, java-8, java-stream

I have an array of size 1000.
I want to use the stream operations to performe like this :-

```
List list= new ArrayList();
//list is initialize to 1000 elements 

  List subList = list.subList(0, 100);
   // perform some operaions over the subarray
  List subList1 = list.subList(101, 200);
   // perform some operaions over the subarray
 .... so on
}
```

I want code using stream API.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you remember that list start with index `0`, right?

Comment: so the ranges are 0-99, 100-199 and so on, right?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher You might want to merge both questions into one comment. It looks silly right now. (flag my comment for removal so it gets removed when you're done).

Comment: yes @SharonBenAsher actually for the first sublist the number of element will be from 0 to 100 i.e. 101 elements

Comment: but `.subList(0, 100)` has only 100 elements. Whereas `.subList(101, 200)` will have 99 elements.

Answer (score 5):

What about :

```
  List<List<Integer>> result = IntStream.range(0, list.size() / 100)
         .mapToObj(index -> list.subList(index * 100, index * 100 + 100))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could either use `Collectors.partitioningBy`:

```
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(element -> list.indexOf(element) >= 100));
and then do:  
List<List<Integer>> results = new ArrayList(map.values());
```

**Update:** 
`Collectors.partitioningBy` takes a predicate and thus is not able to solve the desired use case.

Or if you want to split a list into equal parts (what I think is more youre use case), you could use `Collectors.groupingBy()`:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> groups = 
      list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(element -> (element - 1) / YOUR_NUMBER_OF_PIECES_PER_SUBLIST));
    List<List<Integer>> subLists= new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(groups.values());
System.out.println("Number of sublists " + subLists.size());
```

This gives you:

```
Number of sublists: 5
```

when running with `NUMBER_OF_PIECES_PER_SUBLIST = 200`, which seems your use case.

Comment: @ltFreak im not sure the partitioningBy will work for my condition as the use case of partitioningBy is to dived the list into two parts based on provided predicate.

Comment: @HasnainAliBohra you were right, I extended my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IntStream.iterate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) to achieve that:

```
int sublistItems = 100;
List<List<Integer>> result = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + sublistItems)
        .limit((list.size() + sublistItems - 1) / sublistItems)
        .mapToObj(startIndex -> list.subList(startIndex, Math.min(startIndex + sublistItems, list.size())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you are using Java 9 or above you can simplify it like that:

```
int sublistItems = 100;
List<List<Integer>> result = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < list.size(), i -> i + sublistItems)
        .mapToObj(startIndex -> list.subList(startIndex, Math.min(startIndex + sublistItems, list.size())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) with an **array**, you want to use [`StreamSupport`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html) and a [`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html).

[`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) provides utility methods to create a `Spliterator`.

For example:

```
int[] array = new int[1000];
StreamSupport.stream(Arrays.spliterator(array, 0, 100), false)
  .forEach(e -> {});
StreamSupport.stream(Arrays.spliterator(array, 100, 200), false)
  .forEach(e -> {});
```

Note - it's zero-based indexing, and the start index is inclusive and the end index is *exclusive*.